# Drawing Planar Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Is it possible to draw a planar graph on 11 vertices in which each face (country) has 3 neighbours?

And is there some method after to draw it to confirm that it is in fact indeed planar?
I drew some figures, but then I'm not entirely sure if it is actually planar...

Thanks.

Comment: If your graph is bipartite, then you need to avoid a $K_{3,3}$; for a "simple"graph, you need to avoid a $K_5$, i.e., a graph is planar if it has neither of those two as subgraphs.

Comment: Is the infinite region outside of the graph is also considered  a country?

Comment: If you can draw it without edges crossing, the graph is planar. You should draw it this way to satisfy the statement of the problem anyway. (When we say faces we mean the faces of a planar embedding.)

Comment: For the more general question of planarity of cubic graphs, see Little, "A Characterization of Planar Cubic Graphs", doi:10.1016/0095-8956(80)90080-5 available at URL https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82053241.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the sum of the degrees must be an even number, since $\Sigma Deg(v_i)= 2|E(G)|$. If your graph is "simple", i.e., it is not bipartite, then it is planar iff it does not contain a $K_5$ as a subgraph. Since in your problem, $Deg(v_i)\leq 3$ , it cannot have a $K_5$ as a subgraph, since every vertex of a $K_5$ has degree $4$. If your graph is bipartite, then you have to avoid a $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraph.

Comment: I think I understand the premise that you can do it. But it is difficult for me to visualise... is there some example (precedented or made-up) that you could illustrate??

Comment: Generally simple means that the graph does not have loops or multiple edges. To say "simple" i.e. not bipartite might cause confusion. Your answer is also incorrect: a graph is planar if and only if it does not contain a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. It does not have to contain it exactly as a subgraph. Moreover, the Petersen graph is an example of a graph that is non-planar because it contains a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$, but it is not bipartite. So you must consider both $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$, whether your graph is bipartite or not.